# Why is my console app closed after I call SendKeys?

Tags: c#

I use the following code to communicate with another program using c#:

```
while(true)
{
    Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
    var curLang = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.DefaultInputLanguage;
    //Thread.Sleep(1500);

    SendKeys.SendWait("^+R");
    SendKeys.Flush();

    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = curLang;
}
```

but after SendKeys.SendWait("^+R"); the program terminated with no error. is there any idea what is going on? (Why the while(true) terminated?)

Comment: you need a Console.ReadKey or ReadLine AFTER your while loop. This prevents the application from exiting but will require one last keypress before it exits

Comment: It is exceptionally unclear what the problem is here. There is effectively no context; read it back to yourself as if you knew nothing about the issue and modify as necessary.

Comment: he's asking why the loop exited

Comment: `the program terminated with no error. is there any idea what is going on?` so you wanted to get an error???

Comment: You're communicating with another program through a clipboard? Clipboard is user-space, not application-space. Only use the clipboard when the user asks you to, never for internal application stuff. Also, `SendKeys.SendWait` doesn't work on Vista+, and it always sends to active application - which might be your console application, which doesn't intercept those keystroke messages. You're mixing apples and oranges here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see why an application would exit a while(true) loop without exceptions! The only scenario that I know of for that to happen is if you happen to be on a x64 machine and this to be in a form load event.

That aside,

Here is an excerpt from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

*If your application is intended for international use with a variety of keyboards, the use of Send could yield unpredictable results and should be avoided.*